# Is it really critical if we don't change from AngularJS to Angular?

Tags: angular, angularjs, security

We are using AngularJS project. AngularJS support ends. CVEs are there.  Do we need to upgrade to any other framework? It is just front end framework, data are coming from server.

If we use HTML and JS we are not even going to update anything.

Can anyone say how it will impact if we do not upgrade to any other framework?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to upgrade from AngularJS to Angular. While most of these reasons boils down to performance(migration of animation files from @angular/core for faster performance, use of component-based architecture, etc.), there are many benefits on developers' side as well.

1. It uses TypeScript instead of vanilla JavaScript which has strict typing features due to which, errors can be avoided before runtime.
2. Unlike AngularJS, Angular has built-in official CLI which can aid in faster development.
3. Greater community support.
4. Various angular-specific third-party libraries and plugins.(Angular Material, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-translate)
5. Various Angular specific features.(two-way data binding,interpolation, etc)
6. Staying up to date:- Angular has 6 month regular update cycle to keep it up to date and introduce new features and also optimise existing ones.
7. PWA Support:- Angular 5 introduced service worker, a key component of Progressive Web Apps. While you could use Ionic or a similar framework for mobile support in AngularJS, it could impact user experience.

Comment: You have given answer for AngularJS to Angular and Angular features. But still not mentioned is it really critical.
If you know about cve vulnerability and how could it impact the application